React Native iOS pod install error - Error installing GoogleMaps
I am developing ios app using react native.
When I run pod install, the installation stops with the following error.

Installing GoogleMaps (8.4.0)
[!] Error installing GoogleMaps
[!] /usr/bin/curl -f -L -o /var/folders/_s/b2y1_v7j23j5666ynpqqczd00000gn/T/d20241019-13159-23rzjl/file.tgz https://dl.google.com/dl/cpdc/bad57bdf1f06c544/GoogleMaps-8.4.0.tar.gz --create-dirs --netrc-optional --retry 2 -A 'CocoaPods/1.15.2 cocoapods-downloader/2.1'
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
0  1449    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0
curl: (56) The requested URL returned error: 404

I think installing GoogleMaps because of react-native-maps package.
My react native version is 0.67.4
react version is 17.0.2
node version is 20.17.0
xcode version is 16.0

Check your Google Maps Api key.
As you were getting a 404 error code that means it is unable to get the resources.
Setup your Google API key

Go to the Google Maps Platform.
Google Maps Platform

Go to the Credentials page

On the Credentials page, click Create credentials > API key.
The API key created dialog displays your newly created API key.
Click Close.

Ensure your Api key is restricted for specific platform.


and follow this installation steps
https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/blob/HEAD/docs/installation.md

Thanks. It helped me to resolve my problem.

Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. Can you [edit] your answer to summarize the relevant guidance from the link? Answers on Stack Overflow can certainly link to additional information, but they should stand on their own even if the page they are linking to is later (re)moved. This is important because often, over time, the linked pages are no longer available, which is frustrating for future members of the community.
